# how to hide the adminblog link in the teaser

Tags: theming, users, nodes

how to remove admin`s blog in footer of teasers i can remove the add comment link with this code :

```
function  mytheme_node_view_alter(&$build){
if ($build['#view_mode'] == 'teaser')
{
    // remove "add comment" link from node teaser mode display
    unset($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);

    // and if logged out this will cause another list item to appear, so let's get rid of that
    unset($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment_forbidden']);
}
```

but i can`t remove admin`s blog what can i do ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use something like the below code to hide admin's blog from teaser's view in your theme's template.php, hope it will work for you:

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
      if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
        if ($variables['type'] == 'blog' && (arg(0) != 'blog' || arg(1) != $variables['uid'])) {
          unset($variables['content']['links']['blog']['#links']['blog_usernames_blog']);
          unset($variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: this is work tnx for your tip mrs astha chauhan ;)

Answer (score -1):

Check out the module [Tab Tamer](https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer)

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering,
>   hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab
>   labels.

Comment: tnx for your tip mr pontus but i can`t find any thing about node links in this module!

Comment: @hgp ahh, I see now that it was a link and not a tab you were trying to change :)